# Can I ask here regarding a high school teacher?

Tags: support

I have many problems with a high school teacher of mine in which I feel that some of the actions he performs are undignified and report-worthy. It closely follows the [interpersonal issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpersonal-issues) tag in Academia and I believe that one can face the same situation in the university too. I feel it is more belonging here rather than Interpersonal StackExchange because I want advice regarding taking the appropriate action on him rather than just fixing the relationship with him.

Will the question belong here or should I ask that in Interpersonal StackExchange?

Comment: Note that if you are looking for a non-interpersonal solution (such as filing official complaints, contacting the higher ups, or similar), your question will be off-topic on [interpersonal.se]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expectations and training of teachers, the procedures for addressing grievances, and the roles of various people in the administration, are very different in a high school than in a university setting. (Among other things.) And the academics (researchers, grad students, professors, postdocs) that offer expert answers here on Academia Stack Exchange don't have any special expertise in high school issues.

So, questions such as yours that are specific to a high school setting are outside our domain of expertise, and are off topic here.

I hope you get a good answer on Interpersonal Stack Exchange :)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft has informed me in the comments that stuff like contacting the higher authorities will be off topic in interpersonal SE. Could you suggest where I could ask the question? (I do need help regarding reporting him)

Comment: @SiddharthVenu Sorry, not aware of any such site.